# Delphi TWAChromium error 126

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I have installed the TWAChromium component, dropped one instance on a form but when I try to run the project an error message appear saying:

```
"Exception EOSError in module Project1.exe at 00028B47. System Error. Code 126. The specified module could not be found.".
```

Possibly there is a missing library but I don't know where to find it.

Please notice that I am talking about the TWAChromium component and not the TChromium component. The library that fix the same error for the TChromium component does not work for the TWAChromium.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: You must get [`CEF libraries`](http://cefbuilds.com/) and include them to a path visible to your application. Choose the bitness which matches to the bitness of your application.

Comment: Hi Tlama, thank you for your reply. Still a bit confused. Do you know which one is the download for Delphi XE5. I have downloaded the latest version and it seem to be compiled for C++ Forgive me but I am a bit lost.

Comment: Take the content of the `Release` subfolder in the archive that you've downloaded and copy it to be visible to your executable (ideally just into the folder where's your project executable).

Comment: Dear TLama, really sorry to keep pestering you. Now I have another error message: Exception EExternalException in module libcef.dll at 001277A0. External exception 80000003.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, I found [`one note`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wacef/DjFDhUPeij0/xFyWDn4-nKoJ) that the WACEF upgraded to CEF 3.1453.1236, so I think that you need to use the closest older available CEF version. The older versions you may find on [`this site`](http://www.magpcss.net/cef_downloads/index.php?query=label%3ADeprecated#list). However, I didn't get it to work even with CEF 3.1453.1255 on Delphi XE3 and I'm afraid I can't help any further.

Comment: Thank you for trying TLama. You are a star. I will try and let you know. Could you put your answer into a proper "answer" so I can give credit to you for your effort?

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer with the final solution ;-) I wasn't able to get WACEF to work, but I hope you'll be luckier than me.